# Overlapping values of a variable in decision tree

Tags: decision-trees

Is it okay to have a variable, this variable has values which are subsets of others in the same variable when building a decision tree?

To be specific, I am working with a dataset that have a variable describing types of parking space. Here are the values

parking lot with unassigned spaces;
unassigned parking lot;
parking lot; unassigned;
unassigned parking lot behind apartment;
apartment building parking lot - not assigned;
Parking lot without assigned spaces;
Parking Lot;
Parking Lot;
parking lot;
parking lot;
lot;
apartment-specific parking lot;
gravel lot;
Park in parking area.near where I live;
barn/outbuilding;
Paid parking

I am trying to group some similar values into different categories describing types of parking space. I have trouble with “parking lot” as it is not cleared whether it is assigned or unassigned. Could you help me to classify these values? I am from a non English speaking country so I have really hard time classifying all of this correctly.